# Georeferenced data on animal sightings

Tags: geospatial, geocoding, biology

I once came across a website offering datasets of animal (mainly birds) sightings from all over the globe. If I remember correctly that data was combined from different sources, including crowd-sourced locations (some observations had a column with free text such as "saw it in the garden of my hotel in Addis").

I can't seem to find that data set anymore. Does anyone know this or a comparable dataset?

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few wildlife mapping datasets out there, and growing. Narrowing it down to species' is hit or miss, but if its a hit, you will be happily rewarded, as this data tends to be high quality, and uniquely interesting. Here's a few, look at JellyWatch in particular:
[BirdCast](http://birdcast.info/)
[BirdTrack](http://blx1.bto.org/birdtrack/main/data-home.jsp)
[Christmas Bird Count](http://www.audubon.org/conservation/science/christmas-bird-count)
[North American Breeding Bird Survey](https://www.pwrc.usgs.gov/BBS/index.cfm)
[JellyWatch - Jellyfish Sightings Tracker - this one has user comments as mentioned in the question](http://jellywatch.org/)
[Jellyfish Sightings CSV](http://jellywatch.org/sightings_list/sightings.csv)

EDIT (some related background layers):
[World Wildlife Fund Science Data and Tools - Not wildlife tracking, but wildlife related](http://www.worldwildlife.org/pages/conservation-science-data-and-tools)
[USFWS GIS datasets have more layers for US, and a few wildlife sets too](http://www.fws.gov/gis/data/national/)

Comment: Thank you, this is quite a nice list, I was after larger datasets, covering the whole globe (and possibly more species), but I think your answer answers my question and might be useful to a future passerby

Comment: Thank you also for your edit. I find it weird though that there's not more fine-grained data available to study biodiversity. One would expect that all studies that record animal/insect sightings make their data available after using it themselves.

Comment: np...and yes, one would, but never underestimate the power of greed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Map of Life: https://www.mol.org/about

This resource integrates point observations, species range maps, and assessment of reserves (forthcoming). This database integrates data from GBIF as well with protected areas and ecoregion maps.

Answer (score 0):

I just found: http://gbif.org/. Which seems to be what I had in mind, nonetheless, if someone else finds something useful to add to the list, I'd be happy.